# Can not make div/element movable in nested shadowdom

Tags: javascript, web-component, shadow-dom, custom-element

I can't make my div movable. It is a custom element, that is created by an eventlistener.
Both of these custom elements have their own shadowdom.

[image: Tree structure]
Treestructure

The first custom element is `<web-desktop>` / WebDesktop.js
The second element is `<app-window>` / AppWindow.js

`<app-window>` is created after I click an eventlistener.
Now I am trying to make that "window" (div) movable after it has been created by clicking the button.

However I have been unsuccessful in doing so for several hours.

I included both parts, I strongly believe that the problem is within the AppWindow.

**AppWindow customelement**

```
const template = document.createElement('template')
template.innerHTML = `
<style>
#mydiv {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 9;
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
  border: 1px solid #d3d3d3;
  text-align: center;
}
#mydivheader {
  padding: 10px;
  cursor: move;
  z-index: 10;
  background-color: #2196F3;
  color: #fff;
}
</style>
<div id="mydiv">
  <div id="mydivheader">Click here to move</div>
  <p>Move</p>
  <p>this</p>
  <p>DIV</p>
</div>
`

class AppWindow extends window.HTMLElement {
  constructor() {
    super()

    this.attachShadow({ mode: 'open' })
    this.shadowRoot.appendChild(template.content.cloneNode(true))
    this.appWindowHeader = this.shadowRoot.querySelector('#mydivheader')
    this.appWindow = this.shadowRoot.querySelector('#mydiv')

    this.prevX = undefined
    this.prevY = undefined
    this.newX = undefined
    this.newY = undefined
  }

  static get observedAttributes() {
    return []
  }

  attributesChangedCallback(name, oldValue, newValue) {
  }

  connectedCallback() {
    this.appWindow.addEventListener('mousedown', this.mousedown)
  }

  mousedown(event) {
    window.addEventListener('mousemove', this.mousemove)
    window.addEventListener('mouseup', this.mouseup)
    this.prevX = event.clientX
    this.prevY = event.clientY
  }

  mousemove(event) {
    this.newX = event.clientX
    this.newY = event.clientY
    const rect = this.appWindow.getBoundingClientRect()

    this.appWindow.style.left = rect.left - this.newX + 'px'
    this.appWindow.style.right = rect.top - this.newY + 'px'

    this.prevX = event.clientX
    this.prevY = event.clientY
  }

  mouseup() {

  }

}

window.customElements.define('app-window', AppWindow)

export { AppWindow }
```

**WebDesktop customelement**

```
import { AppWindow } from './AppWindow.js'
const template = document.createElement('template')
template.innerHTML = `
<style>
.resizer {
  position: absolute;
  width: 10px;
  height: 10px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  background-color: black;
  z-index: 2;
}
#appImg1 {
  cursor:pointer;
}
#menuDiv {
  background-color: rgb(23, 23, 23);
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 0px;
}
#menuDiv img {
  margin-left: 25px;
}
hr {
  border: 1px solid black;
  border-radius: 0px;
  margin:0;
  margin-bottom:5px;
}
</style>

<div id="webDesktopDiv">

  <div id="menuDiv">
  <hr>
  <img src="../image/icon.png" id="appImg1">
  </div>

</div>
`
class WebDesktop extends window.HTMLElement {
  constructor() {
    super()

    this.attachShadow({ mode: 'open' })
    this.shadowRoot.appendChild(template.content.cloneNode(true))

    this.menuDiv = this.shadowRoot.querySelector('#menuDiv')
    this.webDesktopDiv = this.shadowRoot.querySelector('#webDesktopDiv')
    this.appImg1 = this.shadowRoot.querySelector('#appImg1')

  }

  static get observedAttributes() {
    return []
  }

  attributesChangedCallback(name, oldValue, newValue) {
  }

  connectedCallback() {
    this.appImg1.addEventListener('click', event => {
      this.createWindow()
    })
  }

  createWindow() {
    let appWindow = document.createElement('app-window')
    appWindow.classList = 'item'
    appWindow.setAttribute('draggable', 'true')
    this.webDesktopDiv.appendChild(appWindow)
  }
}

window.customElements.define('web-desktop', WebDesktop)
export { WebDesktop }
```

Comment: It would help if you create a JSFiddle, Codepen, or inline SO code, so we can run the code... At first sight this: ``.style.right = rect.top`` is wrong .. I think

Comment: Ok, I will proceed to do so.

Comment: I saved (never used it) this: https://javascript.info/mouse-drag-and-drop from my weekly JS newsletter reads

Answer (score 0):

On the `<app-window>`, you should use the `dragstart` event handler and record the position where you clicked in the [`DragEvent.dataTransfer`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DataTransfer) property:

**appwindow.js**

```
const template = `
<style>
:host {
    position: absolute
}
#mydiv {
    z-index: 9;
    background-color: #f1f1f1;
    border: 1px solid #d3d3d3;
    text-align: center;
}
#mydivheader {
    padding: 10px;
    cursor: move;
    z-index: 10;
    background-color: #2196F3;
    color: #fff;
}
</style>
<div id="mydiv">
  <div id="mydivheader">Click here to move</div>
  <p>Move</p>
  <p>this</p>
  <p>DIV</p>
</div>
`
var count = 0 
class AppWindow extends window.HTMLElement {
    constructor() {
        super()
        this.attachShadow({ mode: 'open' }).innerHTML = template
    }

    connectedCallback() {
        this.setAttribute( 'draggable', 'true' )
        this.id = count++
        this.ondragstart = ev => ev.dataTransfer.setData( 'text', JSON.stringify( {
            id: ev.target.id,
            x: ev.clientX,
            y: ev.clientY
        } ) )
    }
}

window.customElements.define('app-window', AppWindow)

export { AppWindow }
```

On the `<web-desktop>` container, you should prevent the default behavior of the `dragover` event, and then define a `drop` event handler to set the new `<app-window>` position calculated from the up and down click difference:

**webdesktop.js**

```
import { AppWindow } from './AppWindow.js'
const template = `
<style>
:host {
    height: 100% ;
    display: block ;
}

button {
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 10px; left: 10px;
}
</style>

  <button>Add</buton>
`
var count = 0

class WebDesktop extends window.HTMLElement {
  constructor() {
    super()
    this.attachShadow( { mode: 'open' } ).innerHTML = template
  }

  connectedCallback() {
    this.shadowRoot.querySelector( 'button' ).onclick = () => this.shadowRoot.appendChild( new AppWindow )
    this.ondragover = ev => ev.preventDefault()
    this.ondrop = ev => {
        let origin = JSON.parse( ev.dataTransfer.getData( 'text' ) )
        console.log( origin )
        let app = this.shadowRoot.getElementById( origin.id )
        let childPos = app.getBoundingClientRect()
        app.style.left = childPos.left + ( ev.clientX - origin.x ) + 'px'
        app.style.top = childPos.top + ( ev.clientY - origin.y ) + 'px'
    } 
  }
}

window.customElements.define('web-desktop', WebDesktop)
```